# What is the (geometic) genus of the image of curve under quotient map of its jacobian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I guess I need to explain my question. Let $C$ be a smooth genus $2$ curve, and let $J$ be its Jacobian. Fix an immersion $\varphi: C\to J$ and we identify $C$ with its image $\varphi(C)$. Now consider the two maps
(1). Let $P\in J$ be a point of order $p$ and $\langle P \rangle$ the cyclic subgroup generated by $P$, and let $f:J\to J/\langle P \rangle$.
(2). Let $\iota: J\to J: Q\mapsto -Q$ to be the involution. And let $g: J\to J/\langle \iota \rangle$.

My question is: How do we compute the (geometric) genus of $f(C)$ and $g(C)$?

I ask this question since I am reading the paper
[Density of rational points on elliptic K3 surfaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9902092.pdf), and I am stuck on the proof of Lemma 2.11.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe this depends on the embedding of $C$ in $J(C)$. For different $\phi$s, you will get different answers.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks. But I don't understand in the link I give, why the authors say that usually we will get rational image.